# where is `SLActivateProduct` in slc.dll?

Tags: windows, winapi

I am trying to dynamically load `slc.dll` to use in activating windows 10 machines, when trying to load the function `SLActivateProduct` it fails and prints the error in the code below, when checking for this function in dependency walker it is no where to be found

```
typedef struct _tagSL_ACTIVATION_INFO_HEADER {
  DWORD              cbSize;
  SL_ACTIVATION_TYPE type;
} SL_ACTIVATION_INFO_HEADER;
typedef GUID SLID;
typedef PVOID HSLC;
typedef HRESULT WINAPI (*SLActivateProductFunc)(HSLC, const SLID *, UINT, const PVOID, const SL_ACTIVATION_INFO_HEADER *, PCWSTR, WORD);
.
.
.
int main(){
.
.
.
    SLActivateProductFunc SLActivateProduct;
    SLActivateProduct = (SLActivateProductFunc)GetProcAddress(hModule, "SLActivateProduct");
    if (!SLActivateProduct)
    {
        printf("Failed to load SLActivateProduct()\n" reset);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

where is `SLActivateProduct`, and how to load it from the dll?

Answer (score 1):

- Library: **slcext.lib**
- DLL: **slcext.dll**